# Windows Xp: Install on Virtual machine in Linux

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to install windows xp on a virtual machine in my linux box. I downloaded virtual machine and using [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-XP-on-Ubuntu-with-VirtualBox), was able to get it to the part of actually pressing start to begin using the vm. However when I press start, I get this:

[image: Virtual box error]

This is what the initial screen looks like:

[image]
[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that causes this error is: The **extension pack version** must match the installed version of VirtualBox. As it says in the error-message: You have to check your extension pack-version.
So have a look at the version of your extension pack and check if it's the same version as the version of the VirtualBox.

That should solve your problem.

**Update**:

Also your Image can be corrupted. Download a trial-version of XP and try to install it.

Comment: Where can I find out about extension pack version? The installed version is 4.2

Comment: @Smac89 Go to the VirtualBox-settings and go to the "Extensions"-tab. Than you can see the installed extension-pack.

Comment: Okay I removed the previous extension pack and installed the 4.2 pack from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), however the problem still persists

Comment: Have you restarted the VirtualBox? I would also recommend to restart your computer to be sure, that everything restarted properly.

Comment: Okay I will do that

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you downloaded an vm-image? If you've done that, I would suggest that you download an windows xp iso and try to use it in VirtualBox. It's possible, that the vm-image causes the error.

Comment: Okay I will reinstall everything again

Comment: No no, that should be the last solution. I would recommend to try first another virtual image.

Comment: How do I get another virtual image?

Comment: You can [download a trial version of XP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=33656).(ISO-file) and than use it as source in VirtualBox you have to choose this iso-file. Than you can install it.

Comment: That trial requires a windows os, so even running with wine, I am not able to get the trial version. However, I will look around for another copy of winxp. Thanks so far

Comment: Than you have to search for another trial.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10787/discussion-between-smac89-and-chris)